# Is it possible that the chestburster becomes the inner jaws of the adult xenomorph?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979

Functionally, the chestburster and the inner jaws seem similar: both are able to penetrate human bone. The mature xeno might grow around the chestburster, probably adding more complex structures as it grows but maintaining its initial form within the adult body?

Comment: A visual argument against this is that the chesburster has the sort of smooth "dome" on the top of its head that the adult xenomorph also has (see the clip of the chestburster [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d5NOwPE-taA)), but the top of the inner mouth does not (closeup image [here](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Inner_jaw)).

Comment: @Hypnosifl: I was looking for a comment perhaps made by writers about this. I am sure that it is probable no one intended the idea I am suggesting but I think it is a reasonable possibility.

Comment: I'd worry more about how a creature with a chitinous exo-shell manages to grow at all, without leaving bits of discarded shell everywhere they go ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin The exoskeleton might soften and reform/expand.

Comment: Then you've found just the right time to shoot them ;))

Comment: @Tetsujin: But they have a wonderful defense mechanism: Molecular Acid which will eat through the hull while destroying all pens in its way, starting with Brett's.

Answer (score 3):

Unlikely unless developed and reshaped around it. The chestburster head carapice has all physical characteristics of xenomorph immature form. [image]
where as tongue adult exhibits ideal top and bottom canines
[image]

Comment: so the chestburster itself might already have underdeveloped second jaws -- but these were not revealed, were they? I think chestburster just drove its body through Kane's sternum by muscular strength no teeth necessary? Or perhaps Kane's struggle reflected the chestburster actually gnawing (yes, they are terrible things, worse than anything almost) in an effort to emerge/burst and escape?

Comment: Maybe they only have one set of "baby jaws" and their second, inner set of "adult jaws" grow in later.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis: just like people... xenos are more like us than we think. if not for the chestburster and cocooning, we could all be friends.